# Executing cross site scripting using html entity

Tags: javascript, php, html, security, xss

I have a question about XSS:

1. As I read html entity supposed to prevent XSS, but reading from the following site: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet#HTML_entities I see they suggest one bypass for example using the following method:

   ```
   "<IMG SRC=javascript:alert(&quot;XSS&quot;)>"
   ```

The html entity here needs to defense against XSS no?

2. Is it possible to inject XSS using HEX?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Using above Payload `<` `>` these both symbols will be converted to `&lt;` and `&gt;` which escapes the input and there will be no chance to to trigger XSS. 
   Ofcourse Html entities are used to prevent XSS attacks but there are scenarios which varies and depends on how website is handling the input.
2. Yes, It's totally possible to use HEX to inject XSS.

   ```html
   <a href=&#x6A&#x61&#x76&#x61&#x73&#x63&#x72&#x69&#x70&#x74&#x3A&#x61&#x6C&#x65&#x72&#x74&#x28&#x27&#x58&#x53&#x53&#x27&#x29>Click Here</a>
   ```

Comment: In this case the < > will not be converted. only this: &quot. So it will run ? As well as why in the recommendation they recommend for defensing XSS in JavaScript variable by using javascript Hex encoding  ? https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.235_-_URL_Escape_Before_Inserting_Untrusted_Data_into_HTML_URL_Parameter_Values

Comment: It totally depends how they are parsing the payload. If it's not converting these < > then XSS will surely execute and it can be simply bypass by using integer value in alert <IMG SRC=javascript:alert(1)>